# I need to set up a for loop to click on several links and then go back to the previous page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, automation

This is my piece of code:

```
my_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@border='1']//a")))
for option in my_list:
    option.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='Javascript:history.go(-1)']"))).click() #to go back to the initial page
```

I am selecting 10 different links from a table using their common xpath and then, for each of them, I want first to click on it and then go back to the table on the previous page. The problem is that the program stops at the first iteration. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: IMO, there is no such element as `//table[@border='1']` on the webpage. Please edit your question and ask about the _actual problem_. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Debanjan I am not working on the homepage (that's were the link brings you), that xpath refers to the html of where i am working, which i don't know how to send to you because the url never changes as i go deep into the site (that is what i wanted to show by giving you the possibility to try it yourself putting the link here)

Comment: Ahhhh, in that case if you can update the question with the relevant _HTML_ it would be easier for the volunteers to construct a well researched answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code:

```
my_list_length = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@border='1']//a"))))
for index in range(my_list_length):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@border='1']//a")))[index].click()
    driver.back() #to go back to th initial page
```

Comment: : I think it will give stale element reference , once you are back to click on second link.

Comment: No. This approach is exactly for avoiding `StaleElementReferenceException`. Note that list re-defined on each iteration

Comment: I ran it but it still gives me "TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ", and the problem is in the 3rd line of your code. Maybe it helps knowing that the url of the page stays the same whatever you click (the site is https://www.coeweb.istat.it/ if you want to check), so it is like I am just moving back and forward inside the same page (pressing the button "back" would work to go back to the same page maybe)

Comment: So it's a single-page application? Does it fail on the very first iteration? Unfortunately I have no access to mentioned URL. Can you try `driver.refresh()` instead of `driver.back()`?

Comment: I think it is but i'am not familiar with the terminology sorry. Unfortunately with "refresh" it goes back of a few clicks and deletes all the options i had set so it might work but it would be very inefficient because i would have to select everything from the beginning and waste many lines of code. With "back" instead it arrives to the same point as my initial code, meaning that it stops after the very first iteration (completing it, so that i am back to where i wanted but it just stops there)

Comment: Hm... It quite hard to provide with a good solution as I don't know about the scenario you want to simulate and I didn't see the other code lines that performs that *"everything from the beginning"*. Can you share the steps sequence of what you want your script to perform?

Comment: @Andersson If you want to see where I am working just click on the link and then follow this: qui.(middle of the page) > Ricerca puntuale (middle of the page) > Attività economica - Valori (Ateco 2007) (under "Dati territoriali" in the middle of the page again) > continua (button located still in the middle of the page) > Class.merci per attiv.econ.(Ateco 2007) - (Valore obbligatorio) (once again pretty much in the middle)

Comment: OK. I will try the same at home because now as I said *"I have no access to mentioned URL"*

Comment: I just updated the question with the screenshot of where i am working and the associated html if it helps

Answer (score 2):

@Andersson answer may cater to your current question but as per the best practices you may consider the following additional points:

- Ideally while you induce a waiter and moving forward you click on an element you should invoke **`element_to_be_clickable`** but as you are invoking an indexed element from a list you have to fall back on  `visibility_of_all_elements_located`.
- To browse back to the previous page rather invoking `back()` method `get()` method on the *base url*
- Your modified code will be:

  ```
  custom_url = driver.current_url
  length = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@border='1']//a"))))
  for item in range(length):
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@border='1']//a")))[item].click()
      # perform your tasks and browse back to the base_url
      driver.get(custom_url)
  ```

Comment: I ran it and I got "TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support indexing". Maybe it helps knowing that the url of the page stays the same whatever you click (the site is coeweb.istat.it if you want to check), so it is like I am just moving back and forward inside the same page (pressing the button "back" maybe would work to go back to the same page). For this reason I am not sure that "driver.get(base_url)" would work because I think it would redirect me to the homepage

Comment: @LorenzoMussetti Try out my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: It happens the same thing as when i tried Andersson's answer with "driver.refresh()" instead of "driver.back()"